# Sharedpreferences with switch button not Save

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, onesignal

OneSignal.setSubscription (true or false) with the help of this button I added a Switch button to the application with the SharedPreferences method; , but the problem is that even though I use SharedPreferences does not save the value of the Button does not save the default value when we restart the application.

```
package com.package.name;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.onesignal.OneSignal;


public class ButtonOneSignal extends AppCompatActivity {

    Switch btn; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one_signal); //Layout tanımladım


    //switch viettel
    btn = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
    btn.setChecked(getFromSP("sw1"));
    btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked == true) {
                OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Active",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else
                OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DeActive",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

private boolean getFromSP(String key) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.package.name", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}

private void saveInSp(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.package.name", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}


public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    switch (buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.switch2:
            saveInSp("sw1", isChecked);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this way?

```
private void saveInSp(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.altaylar.hdfilmizle2017", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked == true) {
                    OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Aktif",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else
                    OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DeAktif",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
```

Comment: @Elshafey so this way ?

Answer (score 0):

add `saveInSp` in your button listener.

`btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                saveInSp("sw1", isChecked);
                if (isChecked == true) {
                    OneSignal.setSubscription(true);                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Active",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else
                    OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DeActive",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });`

Comment: Elshafey so this way ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I ask you to correct the code. Add code please